# Why Visual Studio copies the content of a file and not file itself?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a file called user.json and I've set `copy to output directory` to *always* and *content*. When I change this file in output directory, it changes the content from Visual Studio. So I have user.json: `{"Language":"en:}` and when I change language to French (fr), after compilation it goes back to English. How should I copy file to output directory and do not change the content after build.

I've tried to use `copy if newer` and I've searched the Internet but I'm not satisfied with the answers on it.

Comment: What is the Build Action?

Comment: Which problems do you have with "copy if newer"?

Comment: Thanks, copy if newer worked @KlausGütter

Answer (score 0):

I've changed `copy always` to `copy if newer` with build action `content` and somehow worked.